# Accelerate ball over time

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a ball which need to accelerate during time, but give a very little force. I tried to accelerate with Time.deltatime divided with specific values but it doesn't work.

This is my sample of code (to start game, you need a one tap and ball is moving with constant speed) and my question is how can automatically accelerating a ball during time.

```
void Start () 
{   
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    gameStart = false;

}

void Update ()
{
    if (!gameStart) 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1) 
        {
            gameStart = true;
            GetComponent<Rigidbody2D> ().AddForce (new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f) * force);


        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your approach seems ok to me, what's the problem?

Comment: One more thing, If you set `gameStart` to true in the update loop like this, then in the whole program it will be called only once. Do you set it to false somewhere else again? :/

Comment: I think after some duration you would want to do this acceleration, and to do this repeatedly you may want to use this function http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.InvokeRepeating.html

Comment: I know that program will be called only once, because current situation is that ball have constant speed all time, but I want a ball which is step by step accelerating during time.

Comment: Check my answer below for `I want a ball which is step by step accelerating during time`

Comment: you *can not* call GetComponent inside Update.  Call it once in Awake and assign it to a variable, then use that in Update.

Comment: Why I can't call? This function is call only once (when I tap screen because my ball need to moving when I tap screen, I tried implement input touch on start function but that doesn't work) and have a constant speed. I need a way to have faster and faster ball.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this, I have not changed any variable names to maintain familiarity with your original code

```
Rigidbody2D myRigidbody
void Awake(){ myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>(); }

void Start () 
{   
    Application.targetFrameRate = 60;
    gameStart = false;

    // Invokes the method setGameStartToFalse in 2 seconds, then repeatedly every 1 seconds.
    InvokeRepeating("setGameStartToFalse", 2f, 1.0F);
}

void FixedUpdate ()
{
    if (!gameStart) 
    {
        if (Input.touchCount >= 1) 
        {
            gameStart = true;
            myRigidbody.AddForce(new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f) * force);
        }
    }
}

void setGameStartToFalse()
{
    gameStart = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. That code accelerate my ball every time I tap screen. Seems fine, but problem is with orbit. Before, ball with constant speed have the same orbit(deducted from the edges with angle about 45), with this code, ball have unpredictable orbit.

Comment: **1.** _I want a ball which is step by step accelerating during time_ - if you don't want that then comment this line `if (Input.touchCount >= 1) `

**2.** From you given context I cannot gather anything about this "orbit" and how you made it work in your current context. A little details will be helpful

Comment: **if (Input.touchCount >= 1)** I put this code for only one call (user tap screen and ball will start moving with constant speed). Now, I'm finding a way to giving this ball a little more accelerating during time but without any touch (automatically). I imagine that user play game and that ball moving faster and faster during time. About orbit, ball always have the same orbit like that http://oi64.tinypic.com/14l7n01.jpg :)

Comment: just FWIW you can't call `GetComponent` in `Update`.  I edited in a fix.

Comment: Doesn't work. I have the same problem with " orbit ". Ball unexpectedly have unbelievable speed and orbit.

Comment: @JoeBlow " myRigidbody(new Vector2 (1f, 0.5f) * force); " There is missing something?

Comment: sure, I accidentally deleted the `AddForcce`. By the way you can look at previous edits .. notice where it says "edited 20 hrs ago by Joe Blow" click on that and you see the old versions.  Good luck

Comment: Thank you @JoeBlow very much :) It works fine now  :))

Answer (score 0):

In  `Update()` method you set `gamestart to true` so the application will not execute the code inside the first `if` until you will set again `gamestart to false`. You also must check that [MonoBehaviour](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.html) is enabled or Update will not execute